# Need to convert a string to byte via a input form

Tags: python, input, bit-manipulation, byte, xor

## **Code**

```py
def byte_xor(ba1, ba2):
    return bytes([_a ^ _b for _a, _b in zip(ba1, ba2)])

input1 = input("String 1 > ")
input2 = input("String 2 > ")

key = byte_xor(b'input1', b'input2')
print(key)
```

## **Problem**

I want to xor two strings be first put the strings into the input() forms but the problem is that python need to precise the string after the b'' to convert the string to byte. So i have test it with putting the b'' into the input() form but it dont works

Comment: Your ```b'input1'``` is a byte-like string while ```input1``` is ```str``` type variable storing user's input. Those two things have nothing in common. Putting variable name in quotes wouldn't work. To use ```input1``` variable in ```byte_xor``` function your have to convert it to bytes like this: ```key = byte_xor(bytes(input1, encoding='utf-8'), bytes(input2, encoding='utf-8'))```

Answer (score 0):

Try and replace bytes(xxx) with xxx.encode()